# python text reading

Tags: python, file-io

```
datafile = open("temp.txt", "r")
record = datafile.readline()

while record != '':
    d1 = datafile.strip("\n").split(",")
    print d1[0],float (d1[1])
    record = datafile.readline()

datafile.close()
```

The temp file contains

```
a,12.7
b,13.7
c,18.12
```

I can't get output. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you operating with file handler, but should work on line

like this **d1 = record.strip("\n").split(",")**

```
datafile = open("temp.txt", "r")
record = datafile.readline()

while record != '':
    d1 = record.strip("\n").split(",")
    print d1[0],float (d1[1])
    record = datafile.readline()

datafile.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct code should be:

```
with open('temp.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        after_split = line.strip("\n").split(",")
        print after_split[0], float(after_split[1])
```

The main reason you're not getting output in your code is that datafile doesn't have a strip() method, and I'm surprised you're not getting exceptions.

I highly suggest you read the Python tutorial - it looks like you're trying to write Python in another language and that is **not** *A Good Thing*

Answer (score 2):

You want to call strip and split on the line, not the file.

Replace

`d1 = datafile.strip("\n").split(",")`

With

`d1 = record.strip("\n").split(",")`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will work better for you (comments as explanation):

```
# open file this way so that it automatically closes upon any errors
with open("temp.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()

for line in data:
    # only process non-empty lines
    if line.strip():
        d1 = line.strip("\n").split(",")
        print d1[0], float(d1[1])
```

Comment: It is usually better not to read the content of the file into memory. The Jon Clements is more efficient.  File objects related to the text files supports iteration through the lines naturally.